# How do I get Unix time frame but let's say one minute ago?

Tags: python

So I'm using an API that requires time in Unix and 2 integers, one for the start time and one for the end time.

I'm trying to make it so that the start time is one minute ago and that my end time is now.
I've already writhen the end time but I can't get the start time.

Code:

```py
while True:
    temps = int(time.time())
    temps1 = int(time.time())
    print(temps)
    print(temps1)
    qty = 1
    r = requests.get(f'https://finnhub.io/api/v1/indicator?symbol={symbol}&resolution=5&from={temps1}&to={temps}&indicator=rsi&timeperiod=1&token=c0e6j5n48v6s9jus1ejg')
    e = list(r.json().values())
```

Comment: `temps1 = int(time.time()) - 60` gives you the time 60 seconds ago in `temps1` (or put it in `temps` — I'm not sure which is start and which is end time).  I think you should improve your variable names; the asymmetry is not good (why not `temps1` and `temps2`?), but the names aren't meaningful either (why not `s_time` and `e_time` for 'start time' and 'end time'? — or any other naming convention you choose).

Comment: You should change your API key and remove it from this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
time.time() - 60
```

or

```
endtime - 60
```